# Add to cart alignment on Woocommerce is very off

Tags: wordpress

Got a responsive problem with a website, when the screen is getting smaller, like a small 13" laptop screen, the add to cart button is ending behind the products below. See attached screenshot: https://paste.pics/65423d2ad51cc7e3f0560849f3ac4ef3

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Thanks! Where should i use it :-)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can limit the description lines based on the device screen. For example, I use `max-width: 992px`.

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
   .elementor-widget-text-editor {
      display: block;
      height: 2.6em;
      display: -webkit-box;
      line-height: 1.3em;
      -webkit-line-clamp: 2; /*  */
      -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
      overflow: hidden;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
   }
}
```

```html
<div class="elementor-element elementor-element-6ca2d7e elementor-widget elementor-widget-text-editor" data-id="6ca2d7e" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="text-editor.default">
   <div class="elementor-widget-container">
      Byggepladshegn til netop dit projekt, let og medgørlig som sikrer en go afskærmning, hegnene udlejes med fødder naturligvis, hegnet måler 2 meter i højden og er 3,5 meter i Byggepladshegn til netop dit projekt, let og medgørlig som sikrer en go afskærmning, hegnene udlejes med fødder naturligvis, hegnet måler 2 meter i højden og er 3,5 meter i Byggepladshegn til netop dit projekt, let og medgørlig som sikrer en go afskærmning, hegnene udlejes med fødder naturligvis, hegnet måler 2 meter i højden og er 3,5 meter i
   </div>
</div>
```